# How To Put Navigation In App-Route Angular 2 CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In my app component in the Angular CLI I want to do this...

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And in the navbar component I want to do this...

```
this.activatedRoute.url.subscribe((url) => {
  console.log(url[0].path);
});
```

But the `url[0].path` is always empty. I think it's because the app-navbar can't see the route as it isn't embedded in the router-outlet.

I'm confused though. I don't want to have to create an entire new route just to have navigation in (and then make everything a child). In AngularJS I could add an abstract state and then read the param in the $stateParams in the router config. But how do I do this with Angular?

Comment: do you want to know when the routing has started or you just want to know if a new component is loaded into the router-outlet ?

Comment: I just want to be able to access the url of the router but I can't unless it's a child of router outlet. I would like to have it on the same level as router-outlet....

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would write (subscription to the router (which I guess you already have in your constructor))

```
this.router.events.subscribe((rout) => {
      if (rout instanceof NavigationStart) {
        console.log(rout.url);
      }
    });
```